# Set default background behind an activity's layout

Tags: android

I have an activity with its layout set to an XML file.  the root layout is a `RelativeLayout` and i am setting the background to this layout via `rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_background);`

this drawable, `R.drawable.default_background` has some transparency in it.

It seems as though the default background of any layout is black.  when i set the background to this drawable resource, the default black background seeps through the semi-transparent drawable.

How can i change the default background behind this drawable to white instead of black?

edit: i do not want to change the theme, as that changes more than just background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the root view of the layout a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) which contains your RelativeLayout, and make the FrameLayout's background white.

Comment: duhh, i should have thought of that. :|